# Display custom order meta data value in email notifications

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In Woocommerce I am using *"[Show Woocommerce custom checkout field value in admin order making them editable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54932350/show-woocommerce-custom-checkout-field-value-in-admin-order-making-them-editable/54932470#54932470)"* answer code that display a custom field value in admin order pages and works nicely.

**My question:** Is it possible to display that Custom field value in email notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following to display your custom field "Invoice Number" on email notifications:

```
add_action('woocommerce_email_order_details', 'woocommerce_email_order_invoice_number', 4, 4 );
function woocommerce_email_order_invoice_number( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    if( $value = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_billing_options', true ) )
        echo '<p><strong>'.__('Invoice Number').':</strong> '.$value.'</p>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). tested and works.