# Automatically generate account password ONLY if WooCommerce Payments Express Checkout is being used

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I understand how to enable Express Checkout payment methods (Apple Pay, G Pay etc) on WooCommerce Payments (WooCommerce > Settings > Payments > "Enable express checkouts").

According to this page ( https://woocommerce.com/document/payments/apple-pay/#troubleshooting ) one requirement of Express Checkouts is to enable "When creating an account, automatically generate an account password" (found in WooCommerce > Settings > Accounts & Privacy).

My question/issue is that I would like to ONLY have passwords automatically generated in the case of Express Checkout payment methods. In other words, I would like to allow all other users to set their OWN password during checkout (if they are NOT using Express Checkout payment methods).

I'm trying to determine what filter/hook to use to accomplish this.

Comment: Does this helps ? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54927919/show-hide-custom-woocommerce-checkout-field-based-on-selected-payment-method

Comment: I don't think so because that question is talking about making a custom field visible based on payment method.  My question is about making a setting which is required to use Express Checkout (the auto-generate password setting) NOT a required setting when NOT using Express Checkout. Let me know if you think I have overlooked something.